# Pass optional parameters across chain of calls

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

I have a chain of method calls and I need in a specific target to pass some extra parameters but these parameters are only relevant to that target.
Is there a neat pattern to pass the extra params via some kind of delegate object/cache so that I won’t need to refactor the existing methods and pass `null` in all other cases for the new params?

Comment: method overloading?

Comment: Showing some code here might be helpful.

Comment: You should refactor the code following `Builder` pattern to deal with multiple parameter setters, some [tutorial](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

You only need one parameter for all funcions.

```
Bundle bundle.
```

You can use bundle.putExtra() to put all kind of info in it.

Comment: Isn't that only for between activities?

Comment: No. Of course you can use a bundle as function parameter. You should have tried meanwhile.

Comment: But I would still need to add an extra param (the `bundle`) to all the functions in the chain and it would be only for 1 target call.

Comment: Every function could add its own putExtras to the bundle before it calls the next function with the same Bundle instance. For the rest i dont know which things you have all in mind.

Comment: Yes you had to add that bundle parameter indeed. You could also use a singleton class with holds the data.